# Groovy - Type check AST generated code

Tags: groovy, typechecking

I have a `Groovy` application that can be custimized by a small `Groovy DSL` I wrote. On startup, the application loads several `Groovy` scripts, applies some `AST` transformations and finally executes whatever was specified in the scripts.

One of the `AST` transformations inserts a couple of lines of code into certain methods. That works fine and I can see the different behavior during runtime. However, sometimes the generated code is not correct. Although I load the scripts with the `TypeChecked` customizer in place, my generated code is **never checked** for soundness.

To show my problem, I constructed an extreme example. I have the following script:

```
int test = 10
println test // prints 10 when executed without AST
```

I load this script and insert a new line of code between the declaration of `test` and `println`:

```
public void visitBlockStatement(BlockStatement block) {
    def assignment = (new AstBuilder().buildFromSpec {
        binary {
            variable "test"
            token "="
            constant 15
        }
    }).first()
    def newStmt = new ExpressionStatement(assignment)
    newStmt.setSourcePosition(block.statements[1])  
    block.statements.add(2, newStmt)
    super.visitBlockStatement(block)
}
```

After applying this `AST`, the script **prints 15**. When I use `AstNodeToScriptVisitor` to print the `Groovy` code of the resulting script, I can see the new assignment added to the code.

**However**, if I change the value of the assignment to a `String` value:

```
// ...
def assignment = (new AstBuilder().buildFromSpec {
    binary {
        variable "test"
        token "="
        constant "some value"
    }
}).first()
// ...
```

I get a `GroovyCastExcpetion` at runtime. Although the resulting script looks like this:

```
int test = 10
test = "some value" // no compile error but a GroovyCastException at runtime here. WHY?
println test
```

no error is raised by `TypeChecked`. I read in [this mailing list](http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td5718963), that you need to set the source position for generated code to be checked, but I'm doing that an it still doesn't work. Can anyone provide some feedback of what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much!

## Update

I call the AST by attaching it to the `GroovyShell` like this:

```
def config = new CompilerConfiguration()
config.addCompilationCustomizers(
    new ASTTransformationCustomizer(TypeChecked)
)
config.addCompilationCustomizers(
    new ASTTransformationCustomizer(new AddAssignmentAST())
)
def shell = new GroovyShell(config)
shell.evaluate(new File("./path/to/file.groovy"))
```

The class for the AST itself looks like this:

```
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.CANONICALIZATION)
class AddAssignmentAST implements ASTTransformation {

    @Override
    public void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source) {
        def transformer = new AddAssignmentTransformer()
        source.getAST().getStatementBlock().visit(transformer)
    }

    private class AddAssignmentTransformer extends CodeVisitorSupport {

        @Override
        public void visitBlockStatement(BlockStatement block) {
            // already posted above
        }

    }
}
```

Since my `Groovy` script only consists of one block (for this small example) the `visitBlockStatement` method is called exactly once, adds the assignment (which I can verify since the output changes) but does not *ever* throw a compile-time error.

Comment: can you show a bit more about the plumbing you do? How do you add the customizer and, how do you add your ast modification code? Because if you add after the type checker for example, then it won't be checked

Comment: @blackdrag I add it in the **Canonicalization** phase, which should run before `TypeChecked`. I updated my question with the code I use to attach the AST to the `GroovyShell` and the AST class itself.